# PHP str_replace tags with using arrays

Tags: php, str-replace

I have the following `str_replace` code which takes a given comment string and replaces any instances with a dot followed by `[++]` with the word `He` with a capital letter. Otherwise it replaces with he with no capital letters.

```
$comment = str_replace(array(". [++]","[++]"), array(". He","he"), $comment);
```

Although this works in most cases. It doesnt work if my comment string has `[++]` tag in the beginning of the sentence or if the tag is after a line break or two. It only works if the dot is next to the tag.

Any ideas how I can get it to replace with the capital He if its after a line break or the first tag in beginning of the comment string?

Comment: Turn to the dark side Luke, learn regular expressions

Comment: Might need to use regular expressions....

Comment: I don't see it, you need to show a string that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `preg_replace()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$comment = preg_replace(
    array("~^\[\+\+\]~", "~(\.\s+)\[\+\+\]~", "~\[\+\+\]~"),
    array("He", "$1He", "he"),
    $comment
);
```

Comment: thanks. But it's return a blank result. Seems to be emptying out the entire $comment string.

Comment: @Ahmed, I made an error in the second pattern. Now I've fixed it.